# How do I Expose a non-standard Restful Action

Tags: rest, grails

I'd like to expose a non-standard action within my restful controller.

```
class FooController extends RestfulController<Foo> {

     static responseFormats = ['json']
     static allowedMethods = [lala: 'GET']

     FooController() {
         super(Foo)
     }

    def lala() {
        log.info "IN LALA"
        respond new Foo(code: "LALA")

    }
}
```

but I only get some errors I dont quite grasp

```
| Error 2014-03-17 10:46:07,657 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR 
  errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing 
  request: [GET] /fooapp/foos/lala
  Cannot invoke method get() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
  Message: Cannot invoke method get() on null object
  Line | Method
  ->>  219 | queryForResource in grails.rest.RestfulController
```

Comment: How does UrlMapping look like? Mapping like this should be present. `"/example/custom/lala"(controller: 'foo', action: 'lala')`

Comment: I thought all public methods will be exposed as actions per default? Is that not so?

Comment: Yes they will be, if the default mapping is provided. In that case, you should be hitting fooapp/foo/lala instead of fooapp/foos/lala

Comment: Thx. yeah that works then. Care to put that in a proper answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer on behalf of @dmahapatro since his answer helped me in solving my issue too.

> Inside the grails-app folder, find the conf folder inside which there
>   will be a file called UrlMappings.groovy
>
> **add a line like this for your non-standard RESTful action**:
>
> ```
> "/example/custom/lala"(controller: 'foo', action: 'lala')
> ```